# Сравнение введенной пользователем даты и даты на часах компьютера

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит дату в консоль в формате "дд.мм.гггг". Необходимо на питоне проверить, чтобы указанная дата была не раньше текущей даты (то есть если сегодня 03.08.2023, то даты 02.08.2023 и раньше не принимаются) а также вывести разницу с текущей датой в днях, в противоположном случае вывести ошибку. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, хочу сообщить, что все-таки **StackOverflow** создан для помощи в написании кода, нежели решения задач

Все же, я попытаюсь объяснить код, который поможет вам решить данную задачу

Для начала, для взаимодействия с датами, в Python предусмотрена библиотека **datetime**

```
from datetime import datetime,date
```

С помощью неё также, мы можем получить текущее **Дата:Время** на вашем компьютере

```
current_date = datetime.now()
```

Так, как нам необходима именно дата, то мы из **datetime** используем метод **date**, возвращающий переменную типа **date**

```
current_date = datetime.now().date()
```

Один из способов получения и заполнения данных в консоле предлагается такой

```
datelist = input('Input your date: ').split('.')
```

Мы просим ввести дату, после чего преобразуем его в список, с помощью метода **split**, принимающей как параметр знак-разделитель

После чего используя конструктор класса date преобразуем введенные данные в дату

```
inputed_date = date(int(datelist[2]),int(datelist[1]),int(datelist[0]))
```

Конструктор:

```
date(ГОД, МЕСЯЦ, ДЕНЬ)
```

Сравнивать даты в Python можно с помощью обычных операций сравнения - **"=, <, >= и других"**.

```
if inputed_date >= current_date:
```

Также, мы можем найти разницу дат с помощью стандартных операций *"-"*

```
date_difference = inputed_date - current_date
```

После того, как мы нашли разницу, в найденной нами переменной есть свойство **days**, которое в данном случае и вернет нам разницу в днях

```
print(date_difference.days)
```

Полный предлагаемый код, решающий вашу задачу (если мы рассчитываем на идеальные условия без аномалий, которые вы уже самостоятельно можете обработать):

```
from datetime import datetime,date

current_date = datetime.now().date()
datelist = input('Input your date').split('.')
inputed_date = date(int(datelist[2]),int(datelist[1]),int(datelist[0]))
print(inputed_date)
print(current_date)
if inputed_date >= current_date:
    date_difference = inputed_date -current_date 
    print(date_difference.days)
else:
    print('ERROR')
```